# .htaccess mod rewrite sub directories redirect loop

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to setup a sub-directory with individual .htaccess. I want to redirect .html files to url without extensions and also add a trailing slash and redirect all non-slashed urls there.

Here's my the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test

# redirect urls without trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# remove .html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html

</IfModule>
```

It does work but relative paths get .html added again and again until the max redirect limit. Sample paths that are affected: /css/test.css and css/test.css. /sub/css/test.css works fine.

Changing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}` !-f to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html !-f` or a similar permutation doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

I only want to redirect .html files. What am I missing here?

Comment: At a quick blush, it seems that *%{REQUEST_URI} !index.html* is not right. You want to use REQUEST_FILENAME. As well, it seems that *RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html* is putting the .html file extension back on. Or am I not getting what you are saying?? Cheers!!

Comment: I changed REQUEST_URI to REQUEST_FILENAME with no change. RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html seems to be the problem but it only applies to sub-directories. I dont understand why or what is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: This .htaccess is presumably in your document root? "but it only applies to sub-directories" - that `RewriteRule` only applies to requests that are _not_ directories or files. (?) How do you have  `/css/test.css` _and_ `/sub/css/test.css` - I would have thought only one of those exists (the one that "works")? Your directives only apply to files that don't physically exist. Incidentally if you did a check for `_FILENAME}.html !-f` then you would need to remove the `!` - you are checking that the file exists, not that it deosn't exist.

Comment: No, the .htaccess is in the /sub directory as it should apply to the sub only.  If i remove "!" from the 1st RewriteCond I get Object not found error. If i remove the line I get url like "localhost/sub/file.html/". Everything is contained within /sub directory including /sub/css, /sub/js etc... The paths that work and don't are the same only how they are referenced changes (relative vs absolute). You are right about the !.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was primarily due to the fact that the rule was not specific to .html files. This meant that all files would get redirected including .css files.

Here is a working .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub

# redirect urls without trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# remap url to a .html file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Relative paths within the html file still had to be changed to absolute paths like /sub/test.css

Non-existing URL's (no matching file) still end up with redirect loops which is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. "the rule was not specific to .html files" - although the updated rules still don't appear to be specific to `.html` files? "Non-existing URL's (no matching file) still end up with redirect loops" - you can include an additional check to make sure that the rewritten file would exist _before_ actually rewriting. eg. `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/$1.html -f` - the additional complexity is because your URLs end with a slash.

Comment: You are right, not sure why I thought I made it specific to html... Non-existing page rule worked perfectly. Thanks! Will update the answer when I get all the rules working as desired.