# Redirect $.html to $/ mod_rewrite rule clash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have already remapped URL's from for example /sub/test/ to test.html but I also want to redirect /sub/test.html to /sub/test/ but here seems to be a clash between the rules.

.htaccess files is in the /sub directory and should only apply to /sub directory and any sub-directories under it.

Here's the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub

# redirect urls without trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# redirect .html to url
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
#RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# remap url to a .html file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Logic is that /sub/test.html path gets redirected to /sub/test/ and that is remapped back to /sub/test.html internally.

.htaccess files is in the /sub directory and should only apply to /sub directory and any sub-directories under it.

The commented lines cause a redirect loop to /sub/test/ which is the desired url. If the only the commented lines are left there is no redirect loop so it seems that there is a conflict between the rules. What is causing the redirect loop?

**Non-existent file redirect loop:**

How to deal with non-existing file redirect loops? for example /web.html redirects to /web/ while non-existing /web2.html end up looking like /web.html.html.html....

Comment: Which version of Apache are you using?

Comment: @w3dk Apache 2.2.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing the redirect loop?

When the "last directive" executes, the rewriting process doesn't suddenly stop completely, only the current *pass* stops. The whole rewriting process starts again from the top! The process only stops completely when the URL passes through unchanged (or when it hits the `END` flag in Apache 2.4, as Ivo van der Veeken mentions in his answer).

The "last directive" is either the last directive in the file, or a directive that gets processed with the `L` (`last`) flag.

> `RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]`

So, when the above directive executes, the rewriting process starts again, but this time gets caught by the (commented out) directives above, which strips the `.html` (just added) and redirects. On the next request, the `.html` is added again (for the internal rewrite), but the rewriting process starts again, strips the `.html` and redirects, etc. etc. etc.

To break the loop you can either use the `END` flag (Apache 2.4+) as mentioned above, instead of `L`. Or, use an additional condition (`RewriteCond` directive) on your `.html` *redirect* that checks against `THE_REQUEST`. This server variable holds the value of the initial request (the actual request header sent from the client), not the *rewritten* request, so it will fail to match when the request is rewritten thus breaking the "loop". This works on all versions of Apache. So, try something like:

```
# redirect .html to url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /.+\.html\ HTTP/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

The above condition makes sure that the `.html` exists on the initial request only, not the rewritten request. I don't think you really need to check that it's not a directory, unless you have directories that are named `<something>.html`?!

`THE_REQUEST` looks something like:

```
GET /sub/test.html HTTP/1.1
```

> ### Non-existent file redirect loop:
>
> `# remap url to a .html file`
>   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
>   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
>   `RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]`

Your rewrite directives append `.html` to the request whenever the requested file does not exist. So, `does-not-exist/` gets rewritten to `does-not-exist.html` which gets externally redirected (by your first rule) to `does-not-exist.html/` which gets rewritten to `does-not-exist.html.html`, etc. etc.

You can include an additional check to make sure that the rewritten file would exist before actually rewriting to it. eg. `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/$1.html -f` - the additional complexity is because your URLs end with a slash. In context:

```
# remap url to a .html file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]
```

**EDIT:** To make this more *generic* (to avoid having to include the `/sub` subdirectory), you could try changing the 3rd condition to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
```

This relies on Apache internally stripping trailing slashes from the request.

> make it more portable by making the RewriteBase dynamic

Providing this .htaccess file is in the same directory that you are specifying for the `RewriteBase` directive (which it is in this instance), then you could *dynamically* assign the subdirectory to an environment variable and use that in your `RewriteRule` substitutions.

```
# Removed...
#RewriteBase /sub

# Assign the accessed subdirectory to an environment variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+)/
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDIR:%1]

# Use this environment variable as a prefix to your substitutions
:
RewriteRule (.*)$ %{ENV:SUBDIR}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Incidentally, this is only required for your *external redirects*. You do not need this for *internal rewrites* in per-directory .htaccess files, since the directory-prefix is automatically added back to relative substitutions.

> That would mean that /sub directory could be directory with any name **or even multiple sub-directories**.

For multiple subdirectories you could change the *CondPattern* with something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.+)/
```

By default the regex is *greedy*, so everything between the first and last slash is captured. However, this has potential to break on some URLs/servers and could possibly open you up to an XSS attack, so I would code for your specific requirement, rather than being too generic.

Comment: <something>.html directories are possible so I will leave it in for robustness. How does THE_REQUEST AND REQUEST_FILENAME differ exactly? I cant find much info on it.

Comment: Also see edit, maybe you can chime in.

Comment: The `REQUEST_FILENAME` is the absolute filename on the filesystem that the request maps to. Whereas `THE_REQUEST` is the request header (containing the _URL_) as sent from the client - example shown above. Crucially, `REQUEST_FILENAME` gets updated as the URL is rewritten, which is contributing to the redirect loop.

Comment: I've updated my answer with regards to your "non-existent file redirect loop" update. Incidentally, I also mentioned this in [a comment on your other question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90873/htaccess-mod-rewrite-sub-directories-redirect-loop/91108#comment112625_91108).

Comment: You are correct, the comment was sufficient, I just missed that part. Also is there a way to insert /sub dynamically with a variable instead of hard coding it? Would make it more reusable/portable.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more generic directives. It wasn't really needed in the first one when checking against `THE_REQUEST`, although I've also changed the regex to more closely match the regex in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_.

Comment: Please see the answer I posted with the final .htaccess file. That should make it clear what I mean regarding dynamic sub-directories.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.html` won't work, you'll need `!"index\.html"`, with the quotes. Otherwise it's not a valid regex.

According to the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html), you should use the `[END]` flag instead of `[L]`, to prevent further request processing (internally, your rewrite is reevaluated by the Apache redirect rules). Apparently, there's [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895410/mod-rewrite-end-flag-not-working-in-httpd-2-4) with `[END]` that's only been fixed in 2.4.9 though, so you may have to find another way.

I'd also switch the order of the statements. Most of your links should point to the clean URL, so this should be a bit faster

```
# remap url to a .html file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [END]

# redirect .html to url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: There's nothing invalid with `!index.html` (except that the dot should be escaped). The quotes surrounding the regex are not required here. Quoting the string/regex is only "required" in Apache config files if you have unescaped spaces - in this sense they are just a convenience, since they can always be avoided by simply escaping the space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final .htaccess that works almost perfectly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /sub

# Assign the accessed subdirectory to an environment variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[^/]+)/
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUBDIR:%1]

ErrorDocument 404 /%{ENV:SUBDIR}/404.html

# redirect urls without trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ %{ENV:SUBDIR}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# redirect index.html to sub root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.html
RewriteRule ^index.html$ /%{ENV:SUBDIR}/ [L,R=301]

# redirect .html to url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\ /%{ENV:SUBDIR}/.+\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# remap url to a .html file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:SUBDIR}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

The only change that would be nice is to make it more portable by making the RewriteBase dynamic. I am sure there is a way to dynamically get the /sub directory and use it instead of setting the RewriteBase. That would mean that /sub directory could be directory with any name or even multiple sub-directories.

Comment: I had already edited/added code to my answer to remove the subdirectory (`/sub`) from the `THE_REQUEST` and `DOCUMENT_ROOT` conditions - did these work? I've further updated my answer with regards to making the "RewriteBase dynamic" - by "dynamically" assigning the subdirectory to an environment variable. I see you've changed the order of the directives as suggested by Ivo - personally, I wouldn't do this. Performance is not an issue here. However, readability and debugging is. The natural order is external redirects _before_ internal rewrites.

Comment: @w3dk I didn't see the extended edit till now. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f - I don't see how this would possibly make it work. Where do you set the /sub variable / ENV:SUBDIR? Within the .htaccess or apache config? I changed the order back as suggested.

Comment: Did you try it? In a per-directory context, a request for `/sub/test/` (where `/sub` is a physical directory, but `test` is not a file in that directory) then `REQUEST_FILENAME` _should_ equal `/sub/test` (without a trailing slash), we then append `.html` and test for its existence. You could also try `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:SUBDIR}/$1.html -f`. You set the environment variable at the top of your .htaccess file, immediately after where you would set `RewriteBase` (I commented out `RewriteBase` to try to show context).

Comment: @w3dk Didn't try yet, but what I wanted is actually a completely portable file where you would not even have to define a variable manually. Would be nice to just be able to drop the .htaccess in another sub-directory and have it work. There's probably no simple solution and since I have no plan of reusing this it's not worth putting too much effort in.

Comment: The earlier edits to my answer are intended to represent a "completely portable file". The variable is defined automatically (to whatever directory the .htaccess is installed in), you don't need to manually/explicitly set this. There should be no need (in the directives above) to explicitly include the subdirectory (ie. `/sub`). Making this work using this method for any number of directory levels is a bit more tricky (eg. if the .htaccess file was placed in a directory > 1 level deep). It's made a bit more tricky because your URLs end with a slash, but need to be corrected when they do not.

Comment: @w3dk Ok, its getting confusing with all those edits. I can't find any reference to a variable of a subdirectory either. Which variable should I be using and is there any documentation mentioning it? If so link please.

Comment: `# Assign the accessed subdirectory to an environment variable` - this little rule block creates an environment variable called `SUBDIR`. You then access the value contained in this variable using `%{ENV:SUBDIR}` elsewhere in the config file. The only documentation is in my answer I'm afraid, unless you're after some general info about [setting environment variables with mod_rewrite using the `E` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e)?

Comment: @w3dk I get it now, I thought you were talking about a pre-defined / system variable. The code works except that if RewriteBase is removed a path like /sub/filename will redirect to /home/user/public_html/sub/filename/. I update the answer with exact rules used.

Comment: "if RewriteBase is removed" - yes, because in per-directory .htaccess files the directory-prefix (the absolute filesystem path that leads to that .htaccess file) is added back to _relative_ (not starting with a slash or scheme) substitutions / target URLs. For _internal rewrites_ this is correct. However, this naturally breaks _external redirects_ (which require an absolute URL, not a filesystem path). By using this environment variable we are helping to create this absolute URL, so the `RewriteBase` directive is redundant. (I'm pretty sure the env var can't be used in the `RewriteBase` cmd?)

Comment: Note that the way I wrote the code, `SUBDIR` contains the slash prefix. ie. `/sub`, not `sub`. So you shouldn't include the slash prefix in the substitutions. To resolve your _redirects_ (`R=301`) simply change `RewriteRule (.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]` to `RewriteRule (.*)$ %{ENV:SUBDIR}/$1/ [L,R=301]`. But this is not required for _internal rewrites_ (ie. the directive that simply ends `[L]`). Note that you can't use server variables (ie. env vars) in the _CondPattern_ (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive). See the code in my answer, ie. `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /.+\.html\ HTTP/`.

Comment: @w3dk That worked perfectly! Though one more small issue became apparent where /sub/index get redirected to /sub/filename/ which is not desired. Index should redirect to just /sub/. Not sure why this change caused this or perhaps it was there all along.

Comment: Presumably you mean `/sub/index/`? Yes, that "error" is present in your original directives. Well, it's not really an error - there are no directives that handle that particular situation. `/sub/index` is simply treated the same as `/sub/<anything>`. In order to strip `index` from the request you'll need an additional redirect _before_ your existing directives.